# Dynamic Text UITableViewCell height Attributed Text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have the following code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {
SectionController *sectionController = [_sectionAndRowControllers objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
return [[sectionController rowControllerForRow:indexPath.row] heightForRowInInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];
} 




- (CGFloat)heightForRowInInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), MAXFLOAT);

CGSize size = [[self descriptionString] sizeWithFont:_descriptionLabelFont constrainedToSize:constraint];

CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, kMinCellHeight);

return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2);
}
```

The problem that I have is that some cell have lots of extra padding. I suspect this is because I have "\n" characters to represent logical breaks in the content. I have tried many different methods and posts on the issue, but I can't see to figure out why I have extra space. In some cases, the extra space is quite noticeable.

Comment: can you show a pic?  is the text in the cell wrapping where you have the new line character?